# Matlab remove noise

Tags: matlab, gaussian, noise

I want to remove noise from an image. The image i've been given is a .mat file but it's very complicated because when i load the mat file no image can be seen, then i use imwrite to make it jpg

`imwrite(destroyedImg, 'fr.jpg');`

But when i use imshow I get only colorful dots in white background!

Is there a way to find out how to clear the noise from this picture?!
I'm not allowed to use the internal functions but to build one myself! But i cannot figure out the kind of noise and then remove it! i also have to return the "clear image" in RGB format and not grayscale!

here is some of my code

```
clear all; close all; 
load('image_destroyed.mat');
imwrite(image_destroyed, 'fraou.jpg');
img = imread('fraou.jpg'); 
subplot(2,2,1), imshow(img)
title('Fraou');
H = fspecial('average',[3 3]);
average = imfilter(img, H, 'replicate');
subplot(2,2,2), imshow(average);
title('average');H = fspecial('gaussian',[5 5]);
average = imfilter(img, H, 'replicate');
subplot(2,2,3); imshow(average);title('gaussian');
H = wiener2(img,[5 5]);
subplot(2,2,4); imshow(H)
title('wiener 5x5');
```

[image: Here is the pisture i get in the first place]

Comment: Have you googled how to remove noise yet? Start with a low pass filter for example...

Comment: I've tried already to use the fspecial, medfilt2 and wiener2 funtions in order to understand the kind of noise and then bulid one similar function myself but no luck!
There is my picture http://i42.tinypic.com/n21j7s.jpg

Comment: Please then include the code from your attempts

Comment: Use `imagesc` to view any matrix-like variable (not only gray images). If your .mat is indeed a RGB image, a few manipulations would be needed to view the image properly (like  scaling, clipping and conversion).

Comment: i can only use these functions sort(), ceil(), floor(), zeros(), min(), max(), cast(), size(), imshow(), imread(), imwrite(), imhist(), load() and entropy

Comment: Why are you writing out `image_destroyed` to a jpg and reading it back in as `img`?  A good starting point would be to show us the output of `whos -file image_destroyed.mat`.

Comment: Well the whos command returned
Size:480x640x3   Bytes: 7372800    Class: double     Attributes:

Comment: That possibly explains part of it - some of the image processing function do interesting things if your images are doubles and not between 0 and 1. Was there not a series of numbers under "size", i.e. 1024x1024 or something? Also what does `max(image_destroyed(:))` return?

Comment: Under size i had 480X640X3 as above the max returned 63.7500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DO NOT USE `imwrite` to `'jpg'` to get your image - this only introduces artifacts.
Your input image is of type `double` with values exceeding the range `[0..1]` and thus all the confusion.

```
load('image_destroyed.mat');
image_destroyed = image_destroyed / 255.0; % back to [0..1] range
imshow( image_destroyed ); % should be meaningful now.
```

Comment: That's correct it is meaningfull!!! Now i can see the picture! 
But what was wrong was the double numbers so i had to change them in 0,1 i didn't know how to do that! That's what my fault thank you very much!

Comment: @AsteriosKomertzoglou you are most welcome. good luck with your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The following code, presuming that `image_destroyed` is a variable contained in `image_destroyed.mat`, is probably what is causing the issue:

```
load('image_destroyed.mat');
imwrite(image_destroyed, 'fraou.jpg');
img = imread('fraou.jpg');
```

At **best** this is equivalent to `img = image_destroyed;`, and therefore is unnecessary.  It is possible (and given your strange results, quite likely) that this write/read process is actually introducing further degradation into your image, through inappropriate scaling or clipping, compression, etc.

For MATLAB image processing functions, when using doubles, you should make sure your data is scaled between 0 and 1.